# How to write a constraint that depends on a condition in Circom?

Tags: if-statement, circuit, circom, zkp, zk-snark

I have code of the following form in [Circom circuit compiler](https://docs.circom.io)

```
template DecodeUint(len) {
    signal input x;
    signal input pos;
    signal output value;
    signal output nextpos;

    component getV = GetV(len);

    if (x <= 23) {
        value <== x;
        pos ==> nextpos;
    }
    else if(x == 24) {
        value <== 255;
        pos + 1 ==> nextpos;
    }
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
error[T2005]: Typing error found
   ┌─ "/Users/ilia/compiling/main-circom/main.circom":93:13
   │
93 │     else if(x == 24) {
   │             ^^^^^^^ There are constraints depending on the value of the condition and it can be unknown during the constraint generation phase
```

How do I rewrite the conditions in a form that can be generated into a circuit? Is there something like [Quin Selector](https://github.com/appliedzkp/maci/blob/v1/circuits/circom/trees/incrementalQuinTree.circom#L29) but for if conditions?

Comment: Just use for if

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used `LessThan` and `IsEqual` from circomlib which return either 1 or 0 depending on if it's true of false, then multiplied the output of those conditions by the return value and finally used [CalculateTotal](https://github.com/appliedzkp/maci/blob/v1/circuits/circom/trees/calculateTotal.circom) to sum the multiplied conditions together to get the "result" of all the if branches in an arithmetic way.